# Can I codesign using multiple signatures on one file on macOS?

Tags: macos, sign

On macOS, can you sign an executable with multiple keys?  For example, I would like to sign with the usual Apple Developer account key, but also sign it with an internal key that would be ignored by most machines (root cert not installed).

I ask this because this functionality exists in Windows's .exe signing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - the second attempt will either replace the code signature if forced (-f or --force) or refuse to sign with "is already signed" if not forced.